# Increment Counter

Tags: c#, auto-increment

In my application there is a option for where user creates a simple txt file containing some data. I would like to name the file in sequential order like ST1, ST2.... This sequence will be remain same for all users. if user1 creates a file system should name the file ST100 and then if user2 creates a file then system should name the file ST101.

I cant use the application scope as it is ready only and cant be changed at run time where as the user scope will only impact individual user not across the whole application.

I was wondering is there any other solution to achieve this apart from using database table and tacking sequence.

Thanks

Comment: The simplest solution (and probably the most robust) is to read the existing file names and then generate a name that does not exist already.

Comment: Why you start with 100 and not with 001?

Comment: May be to create some queue? And create those files based on that queue from one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop and `File.Exists`:

```
var dir = @"C:\SampleFolder";
int number = 100; // you want to start at 100
string fileName = String.Format("ST{0}.txt", number.ToString("D3"));
while(File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, fileName)))
    fileName = String.Format("ST{0}.txt", (++number).ToString("D3"));
```

Finally you will have a new file-name and you get the correct path:

```
string path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
```

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: he could put the `File.Create` in a `try...catch`, handle the `IOException` and then try it again (until a maximum-try-count variable is exceeded).

Answer (score 0):

if your application is always on, you can use a global variable for the entire system with the numeric value of the next entry.
if not, you can use a text file as a database with the current number of the file; The problem with this solution is the synchronization, if two users doing the same operation at the same time can give you problems, so it is best to use a database.

I hope it helps you